# Playing .Wav Files

Tags: java, wav

im using

```
String comspec = System.getenv().get("ComSpec");

String fileToPlay = "/path/to/wav/file.wav";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comspec, new String[]{"/c", "start", fileToPlay}) ;
```

and I keep on getting an error all i need it to do is just play a .wav file

Comment: *"I keep on getting an error"* ... really ... are we suppose to guess what it is?

Comment: What error are you getting, exactly? It's hard enough to diagnose a problem remotely -- you're making it even harder by not telling us what the exact problem is. Also, do you really have a .wav file called file.wav at /path/to/wav, or did you copy sample code a little too literally?

Comment: You could use [`Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) to open the associated program for the specified file or the [Sound API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/) to play it your self...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code for an AudioPlayer class that only plays, loops and pauses .wav files:

```
class AudioPlayer implements Runnable
{
    AudioInputStream input;
    Clip clip;
    private boolean running;

    public AudioPlayer(String path)
    {
        running = true;
        try
        {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            input = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(path));
            clip.open(input);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }    
    public void play()
    {        
        clip.loop(1);
        running = true;
    }
    public void stop()
    {
        running = false;
        clip.stop();        
    }
    public void loop()
    {
        running = true;        
        new Thread(this).start();
    }
    public void suspend()
    {
        running = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
        while(running)
        {
            clip.loop(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Its always ideal to make objects that play audio a new thread, so you can play, pause them easily.

The javax.sound API, especially the Clip class, has very useful methods using which you can implement a wide range of sound systems. Make sure to check it out!

If you have any further questions, just put comments on this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try using javax.sound api.

```
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File file);
```

Try running below code, this worked for me.

```
  AudioInputStream s;
        AudioFormat f;
        DataLine.Info i;
        File inputFile;
        Clip c;

        s = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputFile);
        f = s.getFormat();
        i = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, f);
        c = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(i);
        c.open(s);
        c.start();
```